# How to optimize SipHash for 32-bit architecture

Tags: c#, optimization, hash, cryptography

So the somewhat new [SipHash](https://131002.net/siphash/) provides a very fast secure PRF (aka keyed hash function). I use [ch-siphash](https://github.com/tanglebones/ch-siphash/blob/master/CH.SipHash/SipHash.cs#L7), which seems to be the fastest C# implementation around. I get quite amazing performance (1140 MB/s) on my i7 3630QM in 64-bit, but when I switch to 32-bit, the performance drops to 316 MB/s, which is (for my purposes) terribly slow. The SipHash makes heavy use of 64-bit operations, so maybe it's not so surprising, but I would like to know how can I optimize the algorithm for 32-bit processors (notably Intel and also ARM).

SHA512 also makes heavy use of 64-bit operations, yet on the same PC I get 294 MB/s in 64-bit app, and 192 MB/s on 32-bit app, so the drop is nowhere near so significant.

So what cool tricks and optimizations can I do to make the SipHash perform better on 32-bit architectures? Obviously the best I could do is to implement the hash in C++ DLL (using SSE), but I am looking for a managed (portable - needs to work on mobile phones as well as desktop) solution.

[Some have implemented](https://github.com/floodyberry/siphash) the 32-bit version using SSE3, but the performance is not that great either, so maybe that specific implementation could be done better.

There exists [Chaskey](http://mouha.be/chaskey/), a PRF heavily based on SipHash, but designed for microcontrollers (32-bit and less). Unlike SipHash which uses 2 rounds per block and 4 finalization rounds, Chaskey uses 8 rounds per block and 8 finalization rounds. The performance on my CPU was 2-3 times slower than SipHash in a 32-bit mode, so this is probably not the way to go.

Comment: I assume you have looked at the 32-bit implementation comments in section 6, page 11 of the SipHash paper.

Comment: @rossum Yes I have. Lower bound for 64-bit is 3.75 cycles per byte, and 6 cycles per byte for 32-bit. The ratio of 1140 MB/s vs 316 MB/s for the C# does not come anywhere close. But I admit the ratios are pretty close to the non-SSE C++ implementation (which makes no attempt for 32-bit specific optimizations, assuming there are some).